# Duplicate Topics on Meta

Tags: discussion, meta

I've noticed that there are several Questions on Meta that are being duplicated directly, or they have a moderate connection to another discussion on Meta. I'd like to propose that we merge the existing ones(Citing stands out) and try to keep topics in one discussion. This makes it easier for everyone to put their input on the subject and everyone to read it with crossposting or cluttering the Meta.

Comment: good point.....

Comment: There is a mechanism built into the software to vote-to-close duplicate questions. Please vote to close the duplicates as you see fit. We're 6 hours in with 12 questions total. I'm not seeing a need for adding another meta post to address this extraordinarily narrow situation.